# Are there any differences between these two entities relationships?

Tags: postgresql

Below are the two examples of two entities' relationships. What are the differences and which one is better for developing an api? Either of these looks good for my use case. What I need is that - one product should belong to one or many categories and I also would like to query all the products based on a category. Which of these would be more performant?

```
      PSEUDO CODE:

      category: Model.extend({
        products: hasMany(),
      }),
      product: Model.extend({
        category: belongsTo(),
      }),

      AND THIS

      product: Model.extend({
        categories: hasMany(),
      }),
      category: Model.extend({
        product: belongsTo(),
      }),
```

Comment: You should tag the language in which your code is written.

Comment: There is no SQL in your question, so I removed the SQL tag.

Comment: I mean are there conceptually any differences between these two?

Comment: They are identical, you only swapped the names. You can even rename them to a A and B, but you would still be assuming that we know what A and B are.

Comment: You are doing it wrong; both should be `hasMany()` since this is a "N * N" relation. A product has many categories and a category has many products. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for confirming "they are identical" and thanks for noticing that "both should be hasMany()".